# AVCaptureConnection を使って動画撮影時のデバイスの向きを設定したい (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, camera

iOS の Swift を使って、動画保存処理を作っています。

動画保存はできるようになったのですが、 iPhone を縦にして撮った動画をカメラロールで確認すると、横向きになっています。これを回避するために、 `AVCaptureConnection` を使い、デバイスの向きを設定する必要があることがわかりました。

以下の Objective-C のソースをもとに、Swift 版で書き換えようとしました。

```c
AVCaptureConnection *captureConnection = <#A capture connection#>;
if ([captureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    [captureConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];
}
```

実際に書き換えたのが以下のソースです。

わからないなりに、イメージはこうなるのかと思って、強引に書き換えたため、エラーになってしまいますが、これをどのように修正したらよいかわからない状況です。（ネットでいろいろ調べてみましたが、お手上げ状態です）

```swift
var captureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()
if (captureConnection.videoOrientation)
{
    var orientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft
    captureConnection.videoOrientation(orientation);
}
```

どなたか、アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？  
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

実行テストはできていませんが、エラー、警告は消えました。
下記ではどうでしょう？

```
var captureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()
if (captureConnection.supportsVideoOrientation)
{
    var orientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
    captureConnection.videoOrientation = orientation
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
早速、試してみたいと思います。